# Renderer is not working in PathOptions for the Polyline in react-leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, polyline, renderer

I'm trying to add renderer property to PathOptions for drawing the Polyline and here is the code for it:

```
    const canvasRenderer = L.canvas({
        tolerance: 5,
    });

    <Polyline
        pathOptions={{
            renderer: canvasRenderer,
            color: "Black",
            smoothFactor: 1,
            opacity: 1,
            weight: 3,
        }}
        positions={[51.505, -0.09],[51.51, -0.1],[51.51, -0.12],}
        eventHandlers={{
            contextmenu(e) {
                //some function goes here.
            },
        }}
    >
```

Except `canvasRenderer` all other options are applying to the `Polyline`.
How to use the `renderer` property in `PathOption`?

Actually I wanted to create a wider selection area for the lines. As I followed this [solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/466780/6455).

Answer (score 0):

In `react-leaflet`, the `renderer` property in `PathOptions` is used to specify the renderer for the path, but it may not work with all renderers, especially in certain situations. If the `renderer` property is not working as expected, you can try the following:

1. **Default Renderer**: If you want to use the default renderer, you don't need to specify the `renderer` property in `pathOptions`. By default, it uses the SVG renderer, which should work well for most cases.

   ```
   <Polyline
     pathOptions={{
       color: "Black",
       smoothFactor: 1,
       opacity: 1,
       weight: 3,
     }}
     positions={[
       [51.505, -0.09],
       [51.51, -0.1],
       [51.51, -0.12],
     ]}
     eventHandlers={{
       contextmenu(e) {
         // some function goes here.
       },
     }}
   />
   ```
2. **Check Dependencies**: Ensure that you have the required dependencies installed. The custom renderers, such as the `canvas` renderer, may require additional packages to work correctly. Make sure you've installed any necessary packages.
3. **Custom Renderer**: If you want to use a custom renderer like the `canvas` renderer, you should define the `canvasRenderer` variable before using it in the `pathOptions`. Your code appears to have defined `canvasRenderer` correctly.

   ```
   const canvasRenderer = L.canvas({
     tolerance: 5,
   });

   // ...

   <Polyline
     pathOptions={{
       renderer: canvasRenderer,
       color: "Black",
       smoothFactor: 1,
       opacity: 1,
       weight: 3,
     }}
     positions={[
       [51.505, -0.09],
       [51.51, -0.1],
       [51.51, -0.12],
     ]}
     eventHandlers={{
       contextmenu(e) {
         // some function goes here.
       },
     }}
   />
   ```
4. **Renderers Compatibility**: Be aware that not all renderers are fully compatible with all features. Depending on the renderer you choose, some features may not work as expected or may not be supported. Make sure the renderer you're using is compatible with the specific features you want to use.

If you've followed these steps and are still experiencing issues, you may want to consult the documentation of `react-leaflet` and the specific renderer you're using for any additional configuration or troubleshooting steps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 
Here I wanted to increase the tolerance for selecting the lines. So I followed this solution. https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/466780/6455