# Create a wider selection area to select the lines on react-leaflet map

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, polyline, leaflet.draw

Having difficulty in selecting the lines on react-leaflet map, so I have followed the below solutions,

1. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/466747/create-wider-selection-area-to-select-lines-on-map-using-leafletjs

```
     const canvasRenderer = L.canvas({
          tolerance: 5,
     });

    <Polyline
        pathOptions={{
            renderer: canvasRenderer,
            color: "Black",
            smoothFactor: 1,
            opacity: 1,
            weight: 3,
        }}
        positions={[51.505, -0.09],[51.51, -0.1],[51.51, -0.12],}
        eventHandlers={{
            contextmenu(e) {
                //some function goes here.
            },
        }}
     >
```

The renderer was not working and there was no effect on the polylines. That I have posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77098650/renderer-is-not-working-in-pathoptions-for-the-polyline-in-react-leaflet), I think the canvasRenderer wont work for `react-leaflet`

2. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168465/making-a-leaflet-line-feature-more-grabbable

How to use the Leaflet Almost Over plugin with `react-leaflet`.

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Hey - did you ever manage to get a solution for this?

Comment: @JamieBurns, No proper solution just a workaround. I have used `renderer={canvasRenderer}` on entire `MapContainer` not for the single `Polyline`. Now it is working fine.